# How to access an inner object from JSON using Handlebars.js?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am trying to access an inner object from JSON using Handlebars.js. I tried but I am not getting the address object have the area value.

Here is my HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <td>Address</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>   
    {{#empdetails}}
    <tr> 
      <td>{{firstname}}</td>
      <td>{{lastname}}</td>
      <td>{{email}}</td>
      {{#each addres}}
      <td>{{addres.area}}</td>
      {{#each}}
    </tr>
  {{/empdetails}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is my JavaScript:

```
var data = {empdetails: [
  {firstname: "Success", lastname: "Doe", email: "john@example.com",addres:[{area:"mtm"}]},
   {firstname: "Danger", lastname: "Moe", email: "mary@example.com",addres:[{area:"vij"}]},
  {firstname: "ravi", lastname: "m", email: "ramu@example.com",addres:[{area:"chennai"}]},
  {firstname: "sandeep", lastname: "sand", email: "sandeep@example.com",addres:[{area:"mumbai"}]},
  {firstname: "kishore", lastname: "kis", email: "kishore@example.com",addres:[{area:"delhi"}]},
  {firstname: "vivek", lastname: "ve", email: "vivek@example.com",addres:[{area:"vijag"}]},
  {firstname: "adi", lastname: "udathu", email: "adi@example.com",addres:[{area:"guntur"}]},
  {firstname: "prem", lastname: "muk", email: "prem@example.com",addres:[{area:"nellore"}]},
  {firstname: "ramesh", lastname: "Doe", email: "ramesh@example.com",addres:[{area:"mtm"}]},
  {firstname: "naresh", lastname: "muk", email: "naresh@example.com",addres:[{area:"rajamandri"}]}
]};
```

Kindly help me to get the `address->area` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{{this.area}}`. `this` inside an each block corresponds to the item at the current index in the loop.

[Under the "The `each` block helper" section](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html)

> Inside the block, you can use `this` to reference the element being iterated over.